# Convert Spreadsheet values to Formated Text in C#

Tags: c#

I have some values in a spreadsheet like this example:

[image]

I always have at least 2 columns (could be a lot) and also there are always empty lines between the values.

What I want to do: copy these 2 columns, paste in a textBox and when I press a button, I'd like to have this text formatted like this:

[image]

So, basically I need:

- Remove empty lines
- Each value from both columns needs to be between single quotes
- The values from the same line (A1 and B1) must have a comma between them
- Each line must start with "[" and end with "],"
- The last line must not have the ending comma.

Yes, what I need is to convert a excel table to a Java Script matrix, to use on Selenium web browser automation.

I already did one code that's helping me a lot, but just with a single column in excel, to convert it to a simple javascript vector, here's the code:

```
String[] vector = textBox1.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
String vectorFinal = String.Join("','", vector);
textBox2.Text = "'" + vectorFinal + "'";
Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);
```

I'm just starting to study C#, that's why I still have no idea how to do it. Dealing with multiple columns involve TAB characters that are driving me crazy haha ... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother.. let's do a for loop into these excel lines and try to validate if the lines are not empty... For each non-empty line, we should split it again by the TAB character (you must have noticed that when you copy from excel, it separates the columns by TAB)... lets work from you first variable, "vector":

```
//First, you are splitting your text by a line break. Each array position is one Excel line:
String[] vector = textBox1.Text.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
String vectorFinal = ""; //empty string, lets add values here later

foreach(String excelLine in vector)
{
    if (!excelLine.Trim().Equals("")) //if the line is not only empty chars...
    {
        //split the line (ex: "AAAAA 1111" by the TAB character between AAAA and 1111, which is the Excel way to separate the columns. \t is the Regex code for TAB)
        String[] excelColumns = excelLine.Split(new String[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //and add it to your final string: add a new line to the string, starts with [ and '... and ends with ... ' and ]:
        vectorFinal += Environment.NewLine + "['" + String.Join("','", excelColumns) + "'],";
    }
}

//now, just set your textbox text!
textBox2.Text = vectorFinal;
Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);
```

By the way... the above source code will create a string like that:
['AAAA', '1111'],
['BBBB', '2222'],

..noticed the last comma at the end? You will probably don't want it there..
a more professional solution would be to replace the String vectorFinal variable into a List, like this:

```
List<String> vectorFinal = new List<String>();
```

.. this way you could add the values to this List, instead of "vectorFinal += ..." (ignore the NewLine for now):

```
vectorFinal.Add("['" + String.Join("','", excelColumns) + "]");
```

and in the end, when you set your textbox2 text, just do a new String.Join:

```
//join the last array, separating its values for a new line and comma:
textBox2.Text = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, vectorFinal);
```